# Wizzair scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape WizzAir for personal use. Can't understand what's wrong with my code. Could it be incorrect payload object or cookies?

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,lt;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4",
    "Origin": "https://wizzair.com",
    "Referer": "https://wizzair.com/"

}

search_url = "https://wizzair.com/lt-LT/FlightSearch"
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get("https://be.wizzair.com/3.8.2/Api/asset/yellowRibbon", headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
session_id = r.cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"]

cookies = {
    "ASP.NET_SessionId": session_id,
    "HomePageSelector": "FlightSearch",
}

# wizz_url = "https://be.wizzair.com/3.8.2/Api/search/search"
wizz_url = "https://be.wizzair.com/3.8.2/Api/asset/farechart"
payload = {"flightList":[{"departureStation":"VNO","arrivalStation":"FCO","departureDate":"2017-02-20"}],"adultCount":1,"childCount":0,"infantCount":0,"wdc":True, "dayInterval":3}
r = session.post(url=wizz_url,data=payload,headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print r.content


>>> {"validationCodes":["FlightCount_MustBe_OneOrTwo"]}
```

Comment: BTW: with `Session` you can set headers at start using `session.header` and you don't have to set it in every request. And with `Session` you don't have to copy cookies from one request to another - `Session` does it automatically.

Comment: BTW: try your urls in browser and you see that `"https://be.wizzair.com/3.8.2/Api/asset/culture"` doesn't work with GET.

Comment: Sorry, I tested few urls from Network tab and left the wrong one but apparently it's not the main problem here.

Comment: it only comments, not answer with solution. Is there any documentation for this API ?

Comment: I doubt that there's public API documentation. I found it by using Chrome's devtools network tab.

Comment: I have an other Wizzair related question, maybe you can help: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/21103/exploring-api-options-for-ticketing-and-group-purchases-wizzair-and-other-low-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run this - even without session and cookies - and get some data.

You have to send it as `JSON` - using `json=payload`

```
import requests

payload = {
    "flightList":[
        {
            "departureStation": "VNO",
            "arrivalStation": "FCO",
            "departureDate": "2017-02-20"
        }
    ],
    "adultCount": 1,
    "childCount": 0,
    "infantCount": 0,
    "wdc": True,
    "dayInterval": 3
}

url = 'https://be.wizzair.com/3.8.2/Api/search/search'

r = requests.post(url, json=payload)

print(r.text)

data = r.json()

print(data['outboundFlights'][0]['flightNumber'])
```

If you will have to use cookies and headers then use `Session` and then you don't have to copy cookies and headers from one request to another.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36",
    #"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    #"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    #"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,lt;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4",
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

# to get cookies
r = s.get("https://www.wizzair.com/")

payload = {
    "flightList":[
        {
            "departureStation": "VNO",
            "arrivalStation": "FCO",
            "departureDate": "2017-02-20"
        }
    ],
    "adultCount": 1,
    "childCount": 0,
    "infantCount": 0,
    "wdc": True,
    "dayInterval": 3
}

url = 'https://be.wizzair.com/3.8.2/Api/search/search'

r = s.post(url, json=payload)

print(r.text)

data = r.json()

print(data['outboundFlights'][0]['flightNumber'])
```